# Undetermined Banach-Mazur games: beyond DC

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, gn.general-topology, axiom-of-choice, infinite-games

This question is a follow-up to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351663/undetermined-banach-mazur-games-in-zf); see that question for the definition of Banach-Mazur games. There James Hanson showed that ZF+DC proves that there is an undetermined Banach-Mazur game; however, the situation with ZF+$\neg$DC is still open *(there was an error in a claimed answer, and this question has been modified from its original form to accommodate that)*.

I'd like to ask what the ZF-situation is. However, in ZF alone things are rather weird so there are multiple plausible "right" versions of this question. Unfortunately this does make the question rather subjective (presumably based on the answers we somehow pin down which version was "right," but how?), but I think it's within $\epsilon$ of precise for a sufficiently small $\epsilon$.

---

The most obvious question to ask is whether the result, phrased exactly as previously, continues to hold:

> **Version 1**: Does ZF prove "There is an undetermined Banach-Mazur game"?

On second thought, however, it's not obvious to me that this is the right question. Without DC determinacy is a bit weird, and it's arguably better to talk about **quasistrategies**. A quasistrategy lays out a nonempty set of "permitted moves" at each stage, with a quasistrategy **s** being winning for a player if there is no play consistent with **s** in which that player loses and a game being quasidetermined if it has a winning quasistrategy.

A game is *quasidetermined* if one player or the other has a winning quasistrategy. In ZF+DC determinacy is the same as quasideterminacy, but in ZF they are distinct. So we can separately ask:

> **Version 2**: Does ZF prove "There is an un-quasidetermined Banach-Mazur game?"

Yet on third thought, *even that* isn't obviously the right question: it's consistent with ZF that *both* players have winning quasistrategies in a given game! *(Consider "Alternate choosing new elements of an amorphous set.")* So  we might want to land somewhere in the middle - say that a game is *weakly determined* if exactly one player has a winning quasistrategy.

> **Version 3**: Is the statement "Every Banach-Mazur game is *weakly determined*" consistent with ZF?

Comment: My guess is that looking at Gitik's model would be a good starting point.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yeah, I'm looking at it but it's really complicated.

Comment: If it was easy you'd have solved it by now...

Comment: @AsafKaragila I meant the Gitik model.

Comment: I meant the Gitik model as well.

Comment: If it helps, I have a model where every set is the image of a Dedekind-finite set...

Comment: ZF+¬DC implies that there is a BM game that fails to be weakly determined. Take a pruned tree of height $\omega$ with no paths and put the upper set topology on it. The quasistrategy of responding to any move with the cone above some element not minimal in the previous set is winning for both players.

Comment: It's actually not clear to me that DC implies that any weakly determined BM game is determined.

Comment: It's not quite a Banach-Mazur game, but if you're not aware of it already 21.4 in Kechris's classical DST (see also the long hint at the end of the book) asks to construct a non quasidetermined game in ZF, maybe that construction can be modified